# Calculate Italian fiscal code (tax code) in C#

Tags: c#, php, language-translation

I need to calculate the **Italian fiscal code** (tax code) in C#.

I've found a PHP script to calculate this 16 alphanumeric code but I am not a PHP guy and it might take me many hours to translate this script from PHP to C#.

Here the link with the PHP code: http://www.createwebsite.it/script-per-calcolo-del-codice-fiscale

Comment: please post the code here.. thats a downlod page..(no offence.but..i don't prefer downloading zip to answer questions) and i know no italian..:)

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really a translation service. And I'm betting it would take me even longer to translate that site into English first.

Comment: I would also note that you haven't actually asked a question here...

Comment: Its easier to implement on your own

Comment: Just sounds like he wants us to do everything for him...

Comment: I think a little introduction to the problem would be nice instead of just a link.

Comment: The algorithm is public, I provided a link to an implementation in the required language... really don't know what more you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here: http://www.dotnethell.it/forum/messages.aspx?ThreadID=10346 there is an attachment with a class that should do the work.
If you cannot read italian, just look for 185_CodiceFiscale.zip

If you can read Italian, here there is a small project with a step by step guide to build the code: http://www.sviluppo-software.info/2010/01/calcolare-il-codice-fiscale-in-c.html
Should be interesting, if you want to learn :)

Comment: I've finally found what I was looking for.
My apologies if I did express me wrong.

Comment: The second link is missing (`404`), @garph0. Can you also provide link to the algorithm?

Comment: Sure. On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_fiscal_code_card) you can find the translation of the algo as defined in the law's text:  - Please be aware that if I'm not mistaken there may be cases of conflicts in which the code is manually overridden (for instance picking a different letter for the name)